# Does Azure EventHubClient is thread safe?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm working on high scale project that using Azure Events Hub (under ServiceBus).

I writing `Events Publisher` that send events to Events Hub by using the .Net class `EventHubClient`.

Someone know if the `EventHubClient` class is thread safe and can be use from different threads / tasks ?

Comment: Hi, It's not a duplicate, please take a look again and see that for "real high throughput scenarios" the recommendation is not to crate EventHubClient each time. I try to build my own strategy for my high scale scenario and I need to know for sure if the EventHubClient is thread safe.

Comment: I don't think any possible answer will answer it better than http://stackoverflow.com/a/26920160/1012240. The answer there can be summarized as "Currently yes for sending but it's not guaranteed." => "No" I'd suggest asking another question about writing a shared high perf sender if you need more detail. You'll want to identify what you mean by high perf though. You could in principle edit this question to make it not a duplicate, but the question would no longer resemble this initial one.